# Executing command after time has passed

Tags: ruby, multithreading, timeout, sleep

I want to know how to execute a function after a certain amount of time has passed.  The user will enter a duration, say 30 minutes, and after 30 minutes they will be given a message, along with other code being done.  I am new to Ruby, and can't figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: We need to know more about your goal, and also see what you've tried. Do you care whether the code does something while waiting, or is it only necessary that the code goes to *sleep* (hint, hint) a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to block IO you can use threads:

```
time = gets.to_i # time in seconds

Thread.new do
  sleep time
  # your code here
end
```

Or just:

```
time = gets.to_i # time in seconds
sleep time
# your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into gems like [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Resque.](https://github.com/resque/resque)